# Localhost Connection refused by Express Server

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ubuntu, cloudflare

So I have built my server like this:

```
var mysql = require('mysql2');
var express = require('express');
var cors = require('cors');

var app = express();
app.use(cors());

var PORT = 2096;

app.get('/getDataFromDatabase', function(req, res) {
  console.log("Called")


  var con = mysql.createConnection({
    host: "localhost",
    user: "root",
    password: "", 
    database: "casesdb"
  });

  con.connect(function(err) {
    if (err) throw err;
    con.query("SELECT * FROM totalValues", function (err, result, fields) {
      if (err) throw err;
      res.status(200).send(result);
      console.log("Test")
    });
  });
});

app.listen(PORT, () =>
  console.log(`Example app listening on port ${PORT}!`),
);
```

and I'm calling it like this:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $.get('http://localhost:2096/getDataFromDatabase').done(function(data){ 
        for (entry of data) {
            dates.push(entry.date.split('T')[0]);
            totalValues.push(entry.totalValue);
        }
    });
});
```

I have tested all of this on my local PC and it works just fine. I now uploaded it to my Ubuntu Server. Something I might want to add is that I'm using cloudflare and a domain to access the website of course. All request get refused like this (print in console):
`GET http://localhost:2096/getDataFromDatabase net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: The error message refers to a different port than the one you used in both the client and server-side code. The problem isn't caused by the code you have here. Probably you didn't save the JS file or refresh the page properly.

Comment: Sorry my bad, but this isn't the problem. I just tried with a bunch of ports on the server and happened to copy the local version with different port than the error message on the server.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's because you are trying to access localhost but your express server isn't running on your local machine, it's on your domain.

Try:
`http://<yourDomainHere>:3000/getDataFromDatabase`

Also, your domain might be refusing any http requests by default.

Comment: I am using cloudflare with the option enabled to "Always use HTTPS" So all requests to my domain over http will be redirected to https. Could that cause the problem?

Comment: If your express server is running on http then yes.

Comment: @Godzy — The point is that you have to use a URL that the client can use to access the server… which is not running on the computer that the client considers to be "localhost". If your URL uses HTTPS then use HTTPS.

Comment: I have tried changing that. For some reason the URL would not update. It always throws me an error for localhost:3000 even though I'm not using that anywhere. Even when I comment the entire request code out

Comment: localhost:3000 is the default for an express app.  Are you sure the changes you are making at actually getting deployed to your server?  If you commented out the request and it's still trying to make the request would be a red flag for me.